# Redirect After Sign Up and Sign In with 2 Models (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models in my application, User and Admin. So, I put these code in my application controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  root_path
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(admin)
  admin_path
end
```

However, it only executes the last one (admin). So, whenever I signed in as user, I will be redirected to the admin_path instead of root_path as it should be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, in case you have two separate models for `User` and `Admin`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  resource.is_a?(Admin) ? admin_path : root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby understands that you are redefining `after_sign_in_path_for`, so the last one defined will take effect.

You can simply modify your code like this to make it work:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  user.admin? ? admin_path : root_path
end
```

Just make sure `user.admin?` is the function to check whether a user has admin role or not!

Comment: It's not working because I have two models, user and admin. It's separated not one models with two roles.